# How can I integrate my trained yolov5 model with a Django webapp for real-time object detection?

Tags: django, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolov5

Im looking for a way to use my trained yolov5 model for real-time object detection on a Django webapp

I tried saving the model in torchscript format and loaded the model in a function created in views.py. But when I run py manage.py runserver and try to load the webapp in my browser, my laptop camera seems to be on verge of opening but I end up  having an error saying :

> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor
> b (40) at non-singleton dimension 3